# Update CSV column using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have CSV1 (as below) where I have to populate the last column from CSV 2 given below..

CSV1

```
Computer Product       Code   Country Department LaptopDesktop
-------- -------       ----   ------- ---------- -------------
Com1     EliteDesk 705 HP2190 AU      FN 
Com2     EliteBook 830 HP1023 AU      IT
Com3     EliteBook 830 HP1023 FR      FN
Com4     Zbook 15U     HP2020 IN      FN
Com5     OptiPlex 3010 DL1721 FR      FN
```

CSV2

```
Product        Type Code
-------        ---- ----
EliteBook 1030 L    HP1020
EliteBook 1040 L    HP1021
EliteBook 830  L    HP1023
Zbook 15U      L    HP2020
EliteDesk 800  D    HP3035
EliteDesk 705  D    HP2190
Thinkpad L480  L    LE990
OptiPlex 3010  D    DL1721
```

with below code, I'm unable to update 'LaptopDesktop' column in CSV1 whereas output gets appended with -Append parameter or without that, it just overwrite the whole CSV.....How do I fix this?

```
{
$SystemData =@()
$Productinfo = Import-Csv "C:\CSV2.csv"
$Mastercsv = Import-Csv "C:\CSV1.csv"

foreach($record in $Mastercsv)
{
 $mcode = $($record.code)
 $mDLtype = $($record.LaptopDesktop)

 $SysType = ($Productinfo | where {$_.code -eq $mcode}).type
  if ($SysType -eq $null)
  {
    $sysType = 'Unknown, due to non-matching code'
   }

   $AddsysType=New-Object PSCustomObject
     Add-Member -InputObject $AddsysType -membertype noteproperty -name "LaptopDesktop" -value $sysType
   $SystemData +=$AddsysType

 }Return, $SystemData
 }
 $DeviceType= Update-SystemType 
 $DeviceType| Export-Csv 'C:\CSV1.csv' -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fact you've just opened the file to import then try to export to it again is confusing PowerShell.  In any case, it's probably not a good idea to over-write the file in this way as it could lead to corruption.  Probably better to write to a separate CSV like this:

```
function Update-SystemType {    
    Import-Csv ".\CSV2.csv" | ForEach-Object {$codeHash = @{}}{
        $codeHash[$_.Code] = $_
    }{}

    Import-Csv ".\CSV1.csv" |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_.LaptopDesktop = $(if($codeHash.ContainsKey($_.Code)){$codeHash[$_.Code].Type}else{"Unknown"})

            $_
        }
}

Update-SystemType |
    Export-Csv '.\CSV3.csv' -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

If you really want to replace the original afterwards, then you can over-write it like this:

```
Move-Item -Path .\CSV3.csv -Destination .\CSV1.csv -Force
```

Comment: Thanks for your help....mentioned code working however its updating entire csv with several thousand rows..am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Worked fine for me with the example data you posted.  Note that I converted it from your table format to CSV format (i.e. added commas between the items)

Comment: my bad..it worked perfectly for me...Thanks both of you... :)

Answer (score 1):

When posting csv sample data, either use the real comma delimited format -or-
the columnar representation after Import-Csv.

```
## Q:\TEst\2019\01\17\SO_54236818.ps1
$Mastercsv   = Import-Csv ".\CSV1.csv"
$Productinfo = Import-Csv ".\CSV2.csv"

foreach($record in $Mastercsv){
    $record.LaptopDesktop = ($Productinfo|Where-Object Code -eq $record.code).Type
}
$Mastercsv | Format-Table -Auto
```

Sample output

```
Computer Product       Code   Country Department LaptopDesktop
-------- -------       ----   ------- ---------- -------------
Com1     EliteDesk 705 HP2190 AU      FN         D
Com2     EliteBook 830 HP1023 AU      IT         L
Com3     EliteBook 830 HP1023 FR      FN         L
Com4     Zbook 15U     HP2020 IN      FN         L
Com5     OptiPlex 3010 DL1721 FR      FN         D
Com6     unknown       na     DE      IT
```